# Why does `pod install` change the PODS_ROOT path?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

Whenever I run `pod install`, CocoaPods tries to change the `PODS_ROOT/...` to `PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH/...` in the build phase.

I'm not sure why this value is changing just for my Cocoapods setup and not for my other team members. Does anyone know why this value would change?

**CocoaPods Version:** 1.2.1

**Podfile.lock Version:** 1.2.1

**Xcode Version:** Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)

[image]

Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected behavior starting with CocoaPods 1.2.1. CocoaPods is updating here the Check Pods Manifest Lock build phase to support symlinked Pods directories. (See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5499)

So the question would be rather why does it not change for your team members? They might be using older versions of CocoaPods and would be ignoring the warning they should see when running `pod install`.

> [!] The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (1.2.1) is higher than the version of the current executable (#{VERSION}). Incompatibility issues may arise.

If you commit this change, you'll force them to update.